# Netty. Convert HttpRequest to FrameWebSocket and back

Tags: proxy, websocket, httprequest, netty

Can someone help me please?

I'm writing client-server application. Server and client are connected with websockets.
Pipeline for Server:

```
ChannelPipeline pipeline = pipeline();
   pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
   pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpChunkAggregator(65536));
   pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
   pipeline.addLast("handler", new WebSocketServerHandler());
```

Pipeline for Client:

```
final WebSocketClientHandshaker handshaker =
                    new WebSocketClientHandshakerFactory().newHandshaker(
                            uri, WebSocketVersion.V13, null, false, customHeaders);
pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpResponseDecoder());
                    pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpRequestEncoder());
                    pipeline.addLast("ws-handler", new WebSocketClientHandler(handshaker));
```

This application works like a proxy - server get httprequest from outside, then sends it to client via websockets. Client receives it and sends it to modificated specified url, receives response and sends it back to server via websockets. Server receives this response and writes data into Channel that requested it.

The main question for now - what is the best way of converting HttpRequest into WebSocketFrame and back? Current idea is to read HttpRequest in string and then send it as TextWebSocketFrame. In this situation I think I'll need to replace those standart decoder that are specified for server and client currently for do not make double conversation. I did not find such decoder in Netty.

But mayby this is the bad way and there exists some more good decision?
Many thanks for answers! I'm new in netty.

Best regards

Comment: I've used code from HttpMessageEncoder to encode HttpRequest for sending it to WebSocket as BinaryWebSocketFrame. It is working. But maybe there is more better way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to encapsulate the entire HTTP Request, then I think you are on the right track in sending it via a BinaryWebSocketFrame.